# Find the $n$ value when sum of first $n$ terms in GP modulo $p$ is given

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, geometric-progressions

Basically we know that sum of the first $n$ terms in GP is

**$$
s = \frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}
$$**

In my problem $a=1$ and it is calculated with modulo $p$

My equation is

$$
s\mathbin\%p = \left(\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}\right)\mathbin\%p
$$

I have the values for $s\mathbin\%p$ (but not $s$), $p$, $r$ and also given that $r$ and $p$  are prime numbers. Now I need to find the value of $n$, using this information.

Answer (score 1):

This question is from a live contest (Hackerearth June Circuit). You could asked it after the contest.
edit : sorry but i don't have enough reputation to comment.